# How to make simple "casting" templates not require linkage in MSC?

Tags: c++

I have templates in C++ where I put the "meat" in a base class that has DLL export of it's methods, and it's methods takes simple pointers to a base class.

```
class dll_export/import Base {
protected:
    PtrType do-somethign(BaseType &foo);
};

template<class T>
class CastWrapper 
   : public Base
{
public:
  T *doSomething(T &foo) {
      return((T *)do_something(foo));
  }
};
```

The methods wrapped by the template basically do nothing but cast yet when compiling debug the MSC compiler either forces linkage to each variant of the template, or issues a warning 2251 every time it is used in a library exported object. Is there a way to prevent this other than disabling the warning explicitly everywhere and have these simple wrapper methods in the template be forced inline and not require linkage?

I can always explicitly import/export any methods that need to be in the library or put them in the base class.

Comment: [What?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is your exact error message? The above code cannot compile because of missing `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` (or maybe, you should return `foo` directly ?)

Comment: Pardon error in sample code - corrected.  The issue is the "inline" template method if the CastWrapper class is declared as a dll-import/export class, when compiled in debug mode it forces the template methods to be NOT inline and therefore require each specialization to be explitly declared and compiled into the associated DLL.  Understood as the debugger can "trace" through the inline methods.  IF the template is NOT declared as a DLL import/export class then it does compile inline  but warning 2251 is issued if the template is a base class of another DLL-import/export class

Comment: warning 2251 is "non export base class used in exported class" or something like that to indicate the Vtables might not be compatible. ( good to know in some circumstances ) But in this case all objects with VTables are import/export and the only non import/export items are the hopefully inline template methods.